# I am a word (short riddle 2)

Tags: riddle, word

Every P.SE user has me.

Scramble me, then not only P.SE users have me.

Then scramble me and prepend two letters, I am in the heart.

Then change one of my letters, I save people from impending doom.

What was I originally?

Hint 1:

> There are 8 of my original form in a specific type of battlefield.

Comment: Advice: You may want to hold for a while before posting new puzzles :)

Comment: Could you give feedback on my answer and maybe give a hint if it's wrong? I can think of a few things that are in the heart (blood, chambers, artery etc.) and "theater" if it's not referring to an actual heart but the available letters in "the heart", but I found nothing that fits the rest of the riddle.

Comment: @TheRavenQueen Hint added.

Comment: Does scrambling involve more than mixing up letters? For example does it include turning a 'd' into 'b' or 'p'?

Comment: @TheRavenQueen No.

Comment: Is what every P.SE user has limited to P.SE users specifically or can other people also have it? I can't think of anything that is one word and that P.SE users have but e.g. users of other communities don't.

Comment: @TheRavenQueen Not limited.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Every P.SE user has me.

> file

Scramble me, then not only P.SE users have me.

> life - actually, some P.SE users might not have that one :)

Then scramble me and prepend two letters, I am in the heart.

> belief

Then change one of my letters, I save people from impending doom.

> relief

Hint1

> "*There are 8 of my original form in a specific type of battlefield.*"
>  Columns on a chessboard are referred to as "files". There are 8 of them.

Answer (score 5):

Is it

> art?

Every P.SE user has me.

> We all have a little avatar which is **art**.

Scramble me, then not only P.SE users have me.

> Not only P.SE users can have a **rat** as pet.

Then scramble me and prepend two letters, I am in the heart.

> The **aorta** is connected to the heart if that counts as "in".

Then change one of my letters, I save people from impending doom.

> **Morta**. Who else could better avert doom than a goddess of death? *speaking from experience on that one ;)*
>
>  Not so serious alternative:
>  Unless you mean a **porta** (potty), cause not having one when you need it can be a "doomy" experience as can be seen here: [workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87395](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/87395/commanding-respect-as-the-manager-after-an-unfortunate-and-embarrassing-incide)

Comment: Decent work, but doesn't ring to me.